# How to create a solution/project for an existing dtsx package file

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have an existing .dtsx package file and I want to run the package locally from inside of visual studio.

Do I have to create a solution + project and then add this .dtsx file as an existing file to run it locally?

I am using VS 2017.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the *.dtsx file, just create a blank SSIS solution. Once the solution is created, right click on the project and select `Add Existing Item` and select the *.dtsx package. That should be it.

You will need to have SSIS installed, which comes as part of a package in SSDT:

You can download it by [clicking here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086373)

For more information: [Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I don't see a 'blank ssis', you mean just a 'blank solution'?

Comment: @coolbreeze No. In VS2017, you need to have SSDT installed, which is a bundle of three project template types: SSIS, SSAS, SSRS.

Comment: strange, I installed that a few days ago. same file as you linked.

Comment: @coolbreeze It's convoluted pre-VS2019 as it installs its own stand-alone version of VS2017. Check the start menu for `VS 2017 (SSDT)`

Comment: Nope I don't see VS 2017 SSDT.  From your link "Starting with Visual Studio 2017, the functionality of creating Database Projects has been integrated into the Visual Studio installation. There is no need to install the SSDT standalone installer for the core SSDT experience. "

Comment: @coolbreeze Those are database projects. Do you have a screenshot of the template wizard when you create the project? Note: SSIS will be under a heading called `Business Intelligence`